# responsive 3 boxed layout zoom in/zoom out on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to creating responsive 3 boxed layout zoom in/zoom out on mouseover, but can't.

Example: https://www.americaneagle.com/

In American eagle website homepage slideshow below we can find above examples.

Please suggest any example or links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you could try like this.. But do not expect someone else to write your code..

Try yourself first and then ask for specific doubts and clarifications here. :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.grid:after,
.grid:before {
  display: 'table' content:'';
}

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.block {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.block:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  z-index: 10;
}

.block-hidden {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.block:hover .block-hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-hidden">
        Hidden Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-hidden">
        Hidden Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-hidden">
        Hidden Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jones, Thanq for answering. see their homepage for mouse over. Initially content will not appear after mouse over it will appear. Is it possible?

Comment: I have edited the answer.. check it..Positioning of the elements and stuff you gotta do... This is just a concept

Answer (score 0):

each box you can use bootstrap col for responsive
`col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12`
or
`col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12`